# Magento 2 : Image is taking too much time to display

Tags: magento2, product-images, loading

How can I product image load time decrease? The product image is taking too much time to display on home page and all the pages.

[image]

Please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks in Advanced.

Comment: you can optimize images.

Comment: Can you please share URL so I can understand the exact issue. and easy to debug ...

Comment: @testerhello https://testing.choicewholesaleusa.com/